# Sort DIV randomly or by title

Tags: html

i have a grid, containing boxes with images and text like below:

```
   <div id="grid">

<!-- -------------------------- BOX MARKUP -------------------------- -->      
        <div class="box" data-category="Beerary">
            <div class="box-image">
                <div data-thumbnail=".." ></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-caption">
                <div class="box-title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="box-text">
                    random text...    
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>

<!-- -------------------------- BOX MARKUP -------------------------- -->      
        <div class="box" data-category="restaurant">
            <div class="box-image">
                <div data-thumbnail=".." ></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-caption">
                <div class="box-title">Title 2</div>
                <div class="box-text">
                    random text...    
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

and i want to create a button in order to sort the boxes randomly or via box-title. i tried using tinysort like i saw [here](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) but it didnt work.

May i have some help?

EDIT: below its a tried http://jsfiddle.net/vbqL2m82/
I think that somehow i have to flag the box-title in order to sort them.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle, otherwise nobody will help you.

Comment: What does "randomly or by title" mean? Randomly? Or by title?

Comment: Please enable jQuery in your fiddle, otherwise, a good start.

Comment: @oriol I think the OP may want two buttons, one to do a random display and then one to sort by title.